# installing syslog-ng

Tags: debian, nagios, syslog-ng

i have a monitoring server with nagios,cacti and nedi on Debian Squeeze. when i try to install syslog-ng via apt-get i get the errors see below. i think that there is a problem with the sym-links in rc. but i don't know how to troubleshoot this problem.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  libdbd-mysql libdbd-pgsql libdbd-sqlite3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  syslog-ng
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 109 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/350 kB of archives.
After this operation, 705 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously deselected package syslog-ng.
(Reading database ... 39405 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking syslog-ng (from .../syslog-ng_3.1.3-3_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up syslog-ng (3.1.3-3) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K02networker' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'S99nagios' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'nagios' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'networker' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Starting nagios depends on stop-bootlogd-single and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
.
.
.
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv: Starting nagios depends on stop-bootlogd-single and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
.
.
.
Stopping system logging: syslog-ng seems to be stopped already
Starting system logging: syslog-ng.
```

Comment: How did you install nagios, exactly? The debian-packaged nagios has LSB tags in the init scripts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those warnings that LSB tags are missing, it means that in service script /etc/init.d/service_name is missing something like this:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          scriptname
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
```

Simple workaround is to remove insserv (which replaced update-rc.d in Debian 6.0):

```
apt-get remove insserv
```

Or probably better solution is to add those missing tags in all needed scripts.

Here is detailed description of LSB tags on debian wiki:
[LSBInitScripts](http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts)
On this page is nicely described what is LSB:
[Init scripts based on LSB Init Standard](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/lsbinit-script/)